# Kivy Date Picker Validation

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am new to kivy (Python module) and I have added a date picker that displays todays date when it is first loaded , I am looking for a validation that when a person selects a date it notifies the user with an alert if the date is before todays date

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.